# Grep within while loop

Tags: unix, grep

I have CVS file which as search pattern and file name seperated by comma. I want to read the CVS for get search pattern and file and do grep. I tried but its not working. Any pointer in this will helpfull. Please find CSV File(DC2LOGS.csv.

```
SearchPattern,FilenamewithPath
-116329548,/opt/httpd/logs/apps/atasvc/prod3/was70/atasvc-59596/ata.log
-91756,/opt/httpd/logs/apps/atasvc/prod3/was70/atasvc-59596/ata.log
-86160,/opt/httpd/logs/apps/atasvc/prod3/was70/atasvc-59596/ata.log.1
```

Grep code:

```
 cat DC2Logs.csv | while read a b c d e; do grep  -E "CLAManager.getAttributeFromCLAMapping() took.*$d.*"  < "$e";  done;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to do dynamic grep where input and filename comes from CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for:

```
while IFS=, read pattern filename; do 
  grep -e "$pattern" "$filename"; 
done < DC2LOGS.csv
```

(You definitely want `-e` to protect against the leading hypen of pattern causing grep to treat it as an option, and whether or not you want `-E` is up to you.)

Note that this will try to use the first line (the headers), so perhaps you want:

```
sed -e 1d DC2LOGS.csv | while IFS=, read pattern filename; do
  grep -e "$pattern" "$filename"
done
```

instead.

Comment: when i am trying to run following command. i am getting following error. i am using -E option. error:-grep: CLAManager.getAttributeFromCLAMapping() took.*-226746.*: No such file or directory. i dont know how to solve this. i am bit learning unix.

Comment: Replace `grep` with `echo` and see if the command makes sense.  I see now that you want the pattern read from the file to only make up a portion of the pattern, so use `grep -E -e "CLAmanager... $pattern" "$filename"`